# Chamisha Vachamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the Parsha

אשר **נהפך** לנחש

נהפך = 155

Answer (score 1):

One of the holy names 155= 
אלף הה יוד הה

Comment: very timely   .

Comment: Doesn't that add up to 151?

Comment: hmmm... it would appear that it does.  I will get the correct Shem Kodhesh in there in just a bit.